# Understanding GPU clock rates

Tags: gpu, overclocking

I know how to overclock my CPU (mess with multiplier, and bus speed)... However, I've noticed that it seems a bit more complicated with GPU's.

How and where do I start? I've noticed that I can adjust the GPU clock speed in my BIOS.

Card I'm overclocking: http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_240_us.html

I found that memory bus speed is (Mem Speed * Bus width) / 8. So obviously a good way to overclock the memory bandwidth is to adjust the memory speed.

Now, GPU speed is 550 Mhz. How do I find its speed as well? Do I multiply it by the bus width (128)?

What is ideal GPU speed relative to memory bandwidth?

Comment: OC'ing your GPU compared to your CPU is easy.  Just go up in small numbers like Sathya said do some stress testing (3D Mark).  If your system crashes or gets artifacts back your OC off a bit and try again.

Answer (score 1):

> What is ideal GPU speed relative to memory bandwidth?

There's no "ideal" speed. It depends - on the card, the cooling system used, whether it's factory overclocked, the yield of the chip, the power supply in action, the ambient temperatures et al.

The "only" way is to use a software like [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner) and increment the core & memory clocks in 5-10Mhz steps, use FurMurk & check for temperatures and artifacts. Once you *think* you've hit a decent clock speed, fire up [3D Mark 06](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/3dmark06/introduction/) and let it run for couple of hours, or till system crashes - whichever happens first.

IF it crashes, reduce the clocks, rinse & repeat